# Java - inverted index

Tags: java, sorting, indexing

Iam trying to implement a program in java that should be able to take in a list of documents, say 3 for example, then using some single term queries i should be able to get result of how many times the word appears in the documents.

The result should be returned in tuples e.g [doc 1, doc 2]. It should be implemented as an inverted index that runs in memory.

For example if i have:

- Doc 1 : "the fish in the water"
- Doc 2 : "The fish is named billy"
- doc 3 : "the fish is swimming"

searching for "water" gives the result : **[doc 1]**

searching for fish should give: **[doc1, doc2, doc3]**

Iam trying to split the problem into smaller segments so it's easier for me to focus on how to actually implement it. I was thinking more like this:

1) Start with indexing the documents somehow

2) Support single term searches

3) return a list of matching documents sorted by TF-IDF

If we start with point 1, how should i start tackling this problem?

Comment: Just to rephrase your problem: each word should **map** to a **list** of documents containing that word. Doesn't that give you an obvious approach to this problem? If you don't know how to split any given string up into words (or whichever specific part you're struggling with), you should scrap most of your question and just focus on that part instead (because none of the rest of the question would be relevant there and it just makes your question too broad).

Comment: This as an algorithm problem would probably be fine, but you ask for Java code, which extends the scope of this question way too much, as we need to not only explain the algorithm, but also any code we provide, as we don't know what you already know in terms of Java.

Comment: I know the basics of java and a little more. as i said iam trying to focus on narrowing this big problem down to smaller problems so i start with focusing  first on how to indexing the documents, is it possible to use a hashmap for this particular subproblem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `Map<String, Long>` for each document that contains all the words in the document and the number of occurences (search on SO - this has been addressed many times). Using `String::split` can help extracting individual words. You may want to store the words in lower case for easier searching (note that this doesn't work well in certain languages such as Turkish).
2. You can then use `Map::get` to find the number of occurences of a word in each document
3. Output the result

Answer (score 0):

I think Assylias solution is the best. But I would suggest to use Lucene which does exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this example :

```
            String keyword = "fish";
            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(Document doc:documents){
                if(doc.getTextContent().contains(keyword)){
                    results.add(doc);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(results);
```

Comment: This only searches for the word fish in every document right? but how do you store the documents? Should the documents just be stored in the same map as the program or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to compute TF-IDF weights ?

If you're just returning docs that **match** a word, you're doing **boolean retrieval** which doesn't require you to compute any tf-idf. You would need tf-idf if you were doing **probabilistic retrieval** and you're computing scores, etc.